# C++ remote method invoking

Tags: c++, rpc

I have class CPU which is reponsible for process handling, and I queue of processes. CPU side program is implemented on the server and process queue is on the client side. Protocol - TCP.
How can I invoke methods from class process from server, if instance of that class was created on client side.

What is the possible solution for this problem?
Maybe it is easier to pass an object throught network to the server( of course if it is possible )?
 Does C++ provide some sort of RMI library?

Actual my Process class has only one member - string with name, maybe it is easier to pass this string to the server and then recreate an object on the server side?

Comment: There are many libraries for C++, the language itself doesn't provide any remote support.

Answer (score 1):

[CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) is what you actually want. It provides mechanisms for sending messages to remote objects as if they where local.

Comment: Ouch... CORBA might be a bit of an overkill depending on what the user actually needs done. +1 anyway, as even if it gets some time to get things right, once you know it is actually not *that* hard to implement services with CORBA.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Thrift (http://thrift.apache.org/). It's not the only option, but it's very easy to work with and it can also invoke methods and pass objects between different languages. You define a service with a special language, run a compiler that generates C++ code (or any other language you like) for a client and a server, and then you just call methods between machines.

There's a nice presentation about it I put on slideshare if you're interested:

http://www.slideshare.net/dvirsky/introduction-to-thrift

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML-RPC. It is a lightweight and easy to use RPC mechanism. You can get it [here](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/).